# Boot Camp Partition Unavailable After Windows 10 Upgrade

Tags: bootcamp, upgrade, partition, windows

I have a simple problem for you today. I have been using Boot Camp with my Mac Mini for about two years and now, after upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, the Boot Camp partition doesn't seem to appear in the Finder anymore.

I can still boot Windows up by holding the alt/option key at the startup but OS X acts as if the partition didn't exist.

Here are the symptoms:

1. The partition has disappeared from the Finder.
2. Boot Camp tray icon has the 'Restart into Windows' option grayed out.
   [image: Boot Camp Disabled Menu]
3. Disk Utility shows the partition under name *disk0s4*. Moreover, when I hit 'Mount', it immediately gets unmounted again.

   [image: Device Tree in the Disk Utility]

What do you think could cause this situtation?

Thanks in advance,
Pete.

Comment: Did you update to Boot Camp 6 first?

Comment: No, I didn't. I use version 5.1.4 (500)

Comment: v5 doesn't have Win 10 drivers - see if updating does anything for you. I've not tried it myself yet, so not sure of the procedure

Comment: Found [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990) on Apple Support. Now updating Bootcamp to v6.

Comment: Wish you luck. My machine isn't on the compatibility list :(

Answer (score 1):

Reason for that is that windows doesn't fully shut down and goes into hibernating mode where the partition is read only... 
Go into the system setting of windows and uncheck the "fast restart" in the energy settings. Then fully shut down and it shows up.